# SSIS OLE DB Source using providers

Tags: ssis, export-to-excel

I'm using a procedure that uses a table variable to fetch relevant data from my DB, and then returns whatever is stored in that table variable to my data flow.

My OLE DB Source is only designed to run the SQL command EXEC FetchData_prc.

It shows the required columns in the Source Editor, and it also lets me do mapping, preview and all of that.

YET, when running the package, it throws the error: `[OLE DB Source [1]] Error: A rowset based on the SQL command was not returned by the OLE DB provider.`

Comment: Can you add any code from the proc?  I'm interested to see if it returns using a select or if you return the table variable.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to `set nocount on` on your stored procedure to prevent the server from returning the row count.  This could be mistaken by SSIS as the returned result set.  [See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259204%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)